# Velocity of a photon emitted from a particle at $c$

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

Suppose we have some particle $P$ moving with velocity $v_P=c\hat{y}$. At some point during its motion, $P$ emits a photon orthogonally to is own path. The resulting photon would have a classical velocity of $v_L=v_P+c\hat{x}$. I'm trying to understand relativity and more specifically Lorentz transformations. How would I calculate the actual velocity of the photon given this scenario?

Comment: No need to calculate the velocity of a photon - it's always $c$. :-)  If you need to see this look at [velocity addition formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula) and see what happens when one or both velocities are $c$.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier if you start with the particle P moving some velocity *less* than c. You can take the limit later if you like.

The wiki article may be helpful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation

The important thing about the Lorentz transform is what it keeps invariant. I know it's called "relativity" not "invariant-ity" but that's the important thing.

Suppose a particle emits a pulse of photons all at once in random directions. From the frame of reference of a particle that emits light, it does so in a sphere. The radius of that sphere grows at speed c. This sphere of light is often called the light cone. Cone rather than sphere because it's easier to draw cones.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone

Now introduce an observer, O, who sees the particle P moving in the +y direction at speed v. For this observer, the light *still* moves out in a sphere. And it *still* increases in radius at speed c.  The difference is, the center of the sphere from the frame of observer O does not move. That center is located at the point that O first saw the light emerge from.

So each observer sees the light move out in a sphere. And each sees that sphere's radius increase at speed c. Only the centers are different.

Now the Lorentz transform comes along and shows you how that can happen. Look at the wiki page and the section with equations D1, D2, etc.

Now consider the photon that P thinks is moving directly perpendicular to his path. This is *not* the same photon that O sees moving directly perpendicular to P's path. The angle of a velocity will also change, as long as it is not parallel to the path of P. For photons, the angle will change, but the speed will be the same.

So, to get the full vector of the speed of the photon in each frame, you do this. You start with a point on the sphere as observed by P. Then you apply the full Lorentz transform to that point, both time and space coords. And you do the same for the origin of the sphere. Then you recall that the velocity vector is the vector that joins the center of the sphere to the point on the sphere. Note that you need the full Lorentz transform, both t and x. And that if the sphere in P's frame has radius c T then the points on the sphere have time coordinate values that are T later than the origin of the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is wrong.
The rule for adding velocities
$
v_L=v_P+c
$
is  compatible with Galilean relativity, but not with (Einsteinian) special relativity.

The addition formula for relativistic velocities can ([easily](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula)) be found online, and is in fact quite complicated since it collates both time dilation and length contractions between frames.

Comment: I'm aware of the VAF, my issue comes with applying it to my problem